# display rows randomly from a database with no repetition?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 5 questions in my database . I wanted them be displayed randomly and with no repetition . I tried using "order by rand ()" but repetition occurred. How can I avoid repetition ?? Following is the code I have done so far !

```
     <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = 'mySql';
     $dbname = "papers";
     $rec_limit = 1;
     $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass , $dbname);
     if(! $conn )
     {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     mysqli_select_db($conn,"$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");

     /* Get total number of records */
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM quest ";
     $retval = mysqli_query(  $conn,$sql );

     if(! $retval )
     {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
     $rec_count = $row[0];

     if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
     {
        $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
        $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
     }
     else
     {
        $page = 0;
        $offset = 0;
     }

     $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
     $sql1 = "SELECT distinct * "." FROM quest "."order by rand()"."LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

     $retval = mysqli_query(  $conn ,$sql1 );

     if(! $retval )
     {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());

     }

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
        echo '<div class="question-content">'.$row["id"].".".$row["question"]."<br><br>".'</div>';
        echo '<div class="question-options">';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="qn" value="option1" >'.$row["opt1"]."<br>".'</div>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="qn" value="option2" >'.$row["opt2"]."<br>".'</div>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="qn" value="option3" >'.$row["opt3"]."<br>".'</div>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="qn" value="option4" >'.$row["opt4"]."<br><br>".'</div>';
        echo '</div>';
           "--------------------------------<br>";
     }

     if( $page > 0 && $page < 5)
     {
        $last = $page - 2;

       echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'">'.'next'.'</a>';
     }

     else if( $page == 0 )
     {
       echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'">'.'next'.'</a>'; 
} 

     else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
     {
        $last = $page - 2;
        echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last Record</a>";
     }

     mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
```

Comment: Store which question was last, if random question equals last question then re-pick.

Comment: @Script47 It'd be better to keep track of all questions and not just the last one, but this sounds like an algorithm issue more than anything else

Comment: You need to keep track of the questions you have shown and eliminate them from the query. In the query you can use `ORDER By RAND` to get the query to return the random but it will not remove the questions you have already shown.

Answer (score 2):

PHP offers a function called [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), which will randomize an array. It assigns new keys as well. Here's an example of how it works:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
shuffle($array);
```

When you echo the elements of `$array` you will have them in a randomized (shuffled) order. This is a PHP exclusive solution, the manner in which `$array` is populated is dependent on your SQL, and is thus outside the scope of this question.

Comment: The problem here is that you cannot eliminate the questions already shown. Better to use a random query and maintain track of the questions shown in a temporary table.

Comment: Do this. Get your question IDs, shuffle them, cram them into `$_SESSION`, done. `ORDER BY RAND()` will be a performance nightmare at some point in the future.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Code was not edited in until after I had submitted an answer, the pagination requirement was not apparent when I answered.

Comment: "Array to string conversion in C" got this error !!

Comment: @Grin You need to make sure that the result you get from the query is in an array format, then you just need to call `shuffle` on it.